# Updating seperate database when post attachment is changed

Tags: database, updates, pdf

I have a seperate database with lists of users, brochures and brochure URL's, and timestamps of when a brochure was ordered, but I want my database to update everytime a brochure (PDF) attachment is updated in the admin back end of wordpress.

When a user requests a brochure they receive a reminder after a few days wiuth a link to the PDF they requested. I have most of it figured out I just need to know how this link can constantly link to the latest PDF of the brochure they requested.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook into `add_attachment` and/or `edit_attachment` actions and carry out an update on your separate database with the appropriate info. In both cases the attachment ID seems to be the only argument but you can easily `get_post` or `get_post_meta` if you need anything else.

Cheers!